# Access an instance of a class from another class in Kivy (Python)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a program with screen managers within screen managers in an attempt to create a more dynamic UI (I think this causes very poor performance).  The issue is that I need a button in a class within a screen manager to switch the screen on another.

However, the class with the button cannot access the instance of the screen manager because that is in a different class itself.  I have tried to pass the instance in as a variable, but I think that the sequence of events happens in the wrong order, so nothing is being passed.

I have written an example to show what I am trying to achieve.  This code doesn't run because of the issue, but it hopefully highlights my mistake.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class MASTER(ScreenManager):
    pass

class WidgetControlOne(ScreenManager):
    pass

class WidgetControlTwo(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ColourControls(Screen):
    def function(self, instance_of_WidgetControlOne):
        instance_of_WidgetControlOne.current = '_a_'

class AngleControls(Screen):
    pass

class FileOutput(Screen):
    pass

class ConfirmLockOveride(Screen):
    pass

class QuestionApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    QuestionApp().run()
```

**Question.kv**

```
MASTER:

<MASTER>:
    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:

<WidgetControlOne>:
    widget_manager_two_instance_a:
    ColourControls:
        widget_manager_two_instance_b: widget_manager_two_instance_a
    AngleControls:

<WidgetControlTwo>:
    FileOutput:
    ConfirmLockOveride:


<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        WidgetControlTwo:
            id: widget_control_two
        WidgetControlOne:
            widget_manager_two_instance_a: widget_control_two

# Part of manager 1
<ColourControls>:
    # Needs to be able to change screen in manager 2
    widget_manager_two_instance_b:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            on_press: root.function(widget_manager_two_instance_b)

<AngleControls>:
    BoxLayout:

<FileOutput>:
    BoxLayout:

<ConfirmLockOveride>:
    name: '_a_'
    BoxLayout:
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, I think you want to control the left screen from the right screen:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

KV = '''
MASTER:

<MASTER>:
    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main_screen'

<WidgetControlOne>:
    ColourControls:
    AngleControls:

<WidgetControlTwo>:
    FileOutput:
        name: 'one'
    ConfirmLockOveride:
        name: 'two'
    

<MainScreen>:
    manager2: widget_control_two
    BoxLayout:

        # manager 2
        WidgetControlTwo:
            id: widget_control_two

        # manager 1
        WidgetControlOne:
            id: widget_control_one
            main_screen: root.manager2

# Part of manager 1
<ColourControls>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'ColourControls'
            on_release: 
                if root.manager.main_screen.current == 'one' : root.manager.main_screen.current = 'two';
                else: root.manager.main_screen.current = 'one'

<AngleControls>:
    Button: 
        text: 'AngleControls Screen'
        
# Part of manager 2
<FileOutput>:
    Button: 
        text: 'FileOutput'

<ConfirmLockOveride>:
    Button: 
        text: 'ConfirmLockOveride'
'''


class MASTER(ScreenManager):
    pass


class WidgetControlOne(ScreenManager):
    pass


class WidgetControlTwo(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ColourControls(Screen):
    pass


class AngleControls(Screen):
    pass


class FileOutput(Screen):
    pass


class ConfirmLockOveride(Screen):
    pass


class QuestionApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    QuestionApp().run()
```